# Can't access ASA website to download ASDM launcher

Tags: cisco-asa

Hoping someone can give me a pointer on here.  I recently took a new position and am currently trying to learn the new system.  I'm having trouble getting to ASDM and have Googled plenty to no avail.

I can access the ASA via Putty/SSH and see in the config that http server enable is there.  One of the networks allowed is the network I'm currently in.  My boss can get to it successfully from the same network.

At my previous job I used this all the time and never had any issues, and from what I can tell everything is set up similarly.

When I attempt to get to https://x.x.x.x I get "Connection Refused".  It doesn't specify a different port when I do the Sh Run so I believe it is still set to 443.

Any suggestions?  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Do you have a service contract? Cisco doesn't usually provide their utilities to the public for free.

Comment: Try adding `http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 $interface` to the ASA's config to see if that's the issue (note: replace $interface with the name of your internal interface, commonly "inside"). Also, check your browser for Proxy settings that might be screwing up the connection.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy I don't think he's trying to download ASDM. I think he's trying to get to the ASDM interface on the ASA.

Comment: Correct, the ASA has the image already, I just can't seem to get to it from my machine to run the launcher.  I'll look into the proxy settings and try for the 0.0.0.0 addition.  Thanks, I'll get back with you all shortly.

Comment: As Chris said, verify what is showing in http <etc>.  That's probably the issue.  It could be that you're seeing `ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside` in the config (allowing you to SSH to it) but not necessarily the same for the http line for ASDM access.

Comment: Proxy is at least part of the problem!!  Thanks!  I can now get to it to install the launcher.  However, when I go to run it I get "Unable to launch device manager from 10.10.10.2".  Ideas?

Comment: Just for more information, here is the image I am using: asdm image disk0:/asdm-711-52.bin.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Java version. If you already have Java 7u51 you need ASDM 7.1.5-100.
Downgrade to Java 7u45 for older ASDM versions. In Java 7u51 only WebStart is supported.